# In dialogflow chat, how do I mask an entered text that happens to be the pin/password?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Dialogflow chat, by default, displays all text unmasked. At a point in the conversation that chat will ask the user for a pin/password. I need this entered pin to be masked (printed as ****) on the chat.

How do I achieve this?

Expect result: After the user has typed in the Pin, it should be displayed as *** on the chat screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it. You may consider to use account linking for these kind of action. For more information you can check:
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to handle through the UI itself. When you ask the user to enter a password, show a password box to restrict the user to enter the password and you can put input type as password depending on the platform you are using.

Comment: I am new to dialogflow. Using google assistant as the platform. How do we achieve this in google assistant?

Comment: GA might not have that. Please check the sdk samples that you are using as for GA, UI is controlled via sdk only

Comment: I have developed it with the response JSON mostly(returned by a node server). did not use SDK.

Comment: Using sdk I the best way.